# Get PDF files and image files from Dropbox to Android mobile?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to get the pdf and image files from Dropbox to Listview in my Android application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [Android SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) for the Dropbox API to get a list of files, including PDFs and images, to display in your list view:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String)

You can also download files as desired:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.OutputStream, com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFileStream(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

You can also search for files by a particular file extension using the search call:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#search
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#search(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Can, with mobile phone version of the PFD suddenly can ah, you can look for some software mall, there are free
http://www.cusabio.com/bio1-B-B2M-7-0.html

Comment: No.I don't want PFD.I am asking about PDF.